# Entity Framework 7 Reverse Engineering doesn't work

Tags: reverse-engineering, asp.net-core, dnx, entity-framework-core

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.
And this is my project.json and global.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Application.Data Class Library",
  "authors": [ "------" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-15886",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-15945",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-15945",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-rc1-15886"
  },

  "commands": {
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  }  
}
```

and

```
{
  "projects": [ "Application.Data", "Application.WebApi" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-16048",
    "runtime": "clr",
    "architecture": "x86"
  }
}
```

When I run dnx ef I get this message error

```
C:\Users\-------\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Application\Application.Data>dnx ef --help
System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.IRuntimeEnvironment' has been registered.
   à Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   à Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   à Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program..ctor(IServiceProvider dnxServices)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dnx version `rc1-16048` is the latest but you're using old versions of EF (and conflicting versions). Also, `SqlServer` [has been renamed](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/85) to `MicrosoftSqlServer`. [The latest versions as of this writing are:](https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetvnext)

```
"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-16147",
"EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-16147",
"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-16147",
"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-rc1-16147"
```